# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: TRACE

Tags: java, hibernate, log4j

I am developing a project which accesses the database but im having some problems. I try to use hibernate 3.2 and 4.52 but it doesn't work.

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.jboss.logging).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: TRACE
    at org.jboss.logging.Log4jLogger.translate(Log4jLogger.java:60)
    at org.jboss.logging.Log4jLogger.isEnabled(Log4jLogger.java:35)
    at org.jboss.logging.Logger.logv(Logger.java:1953)
    at org.jboss.logging.DelegatingBasicLogger.tracev(DelegatingBasicLogger.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.EJB3DTDEntityResolver.resolveEntity(EJB3DTDEntityResolver.java:59)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.EntityResolverWrapper.resolveEntity(EntityResolverWrapper.java:110)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.resolveEntityAsPerStax(XMLEntityManager.java:994)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.dispatch(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1154)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1050)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:964)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:117)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:649)
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:465)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2157)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2077)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2056)
    at aucas.Aucas.<init>(Aucas.java:38)
    at aucas.Aucas.main(Aucas.java:45)
```

the exception is in this lines of code

```
public Aucas() {
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    LoginDialog d = new LoginDialog(null,false,this);
}
```

Comment: This cannot be answered unless you show some related things such the code which might be associated with cause of the exception. `java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: TRACE` - what is `TRACE`? It appears that you have an incorrect/invalid/missing log4j dependency.

Comment: Sorry, I dont know what trace is about im using openswing netbeans and hibernate .

Comment: This is a dependency problem and cannot be applied at all to the reason to close this question - to the close voters.

Comment: I am unable to post another answer since the question was closed. But another solution is that the line of code in Log4jLogger refers to a unsupported TRACE level in org.apache.log4j.Level (old version). This issue can occur if this class is used elsewhere in a jar file, not necessarily log4j. That dependency will need to be removed.

Comment: this is a great question and a great answer accepted below.  there is something broken in the stack overflow "soup nazi" process....

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to check for conflicting version  of class org.apache.log4j.Level in your classpath and resolve it. The TRACE level is available in the log4j jar of version 1.2.12 or higher.