# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.dom4j.io.STAXEventReader

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven, dom4j

I am developing a web service application but sessionFactory bean is not creating because of below error. I can't see duplicate or conflict version of dom4j jar. I tried various times to referesh/clean server and project in eclipse.

> Hibernate version 5.1.0.Final

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-database.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/dom4j/io/STAXEventReader
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1192)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1116)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545)
... 51 more


Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/dom4j/io/STAXEventReader
      at org.hibernate.boot.spi.XmlMappingBinderAccess.<init>(XmlMappingBinderAccess.java:43)
      at org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources.<init>(MetadataSources.java:87)
      at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:124)
      at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.<init>(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:110)
      at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:309)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637)
      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
... 61 more


Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.dom4j.io.STAXEventReader from [Module "deployment.web-services.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
      at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:205)
      at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:455)
      at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:404)
      at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:385)
      at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:130)
... 68 more
```

Spring-security.xml

```
<?xml  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean"> 
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>com.foo.bar.entity</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
            <prop key="current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.validator.apply_to_ddl">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.validator.autoregister_listeners">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
<!-- Transcation Manager -->
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:jboss/datasources/myDS" />
</bean>
```

maven dependency:tree command give below result:-

```
--- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ web-services ---
[INFO] com.car.buk:web-services:war:1.0
[INFO] +- com.car.buk:user-management:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.car.buk:entity:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.18:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.5.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.5.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.5.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.20.0-GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jta_1.1_spec:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss:jandex:jar:2.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:5.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:4.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:4.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.2.5.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:4.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:4.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-acl:jar:4.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:4.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2:jar:2.0.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.9:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO] \- junit:junit:jar:3.8.1:test
```

I am totally stuck. Do any of you guys have any clue how to resolve this??

Comment: in the error message you got `Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/dom4j/io/STAXEventReader
` maybe you got the wrong version of the jar `dom4j` : try to search the class in the jar : if you don't find it search another version of `dom4j` wich contain the class `STAXEventReader` . i used the version 1.6 wich contain the class so try it

Comment: dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1 is jar used and it is added by hibernate core 5.1.0.final. I have checked the class is present in this version also. should I exclude this jar and include 1.6?? @Hohenheim

Comment: Try it because in my case it worked and hope that will for you too

Comment: @Hohenheim This is cool...It worked!!! Thanks alot. This is weird... Why hibernate core is depends on dom4j1.6.1?? shouldn't be dom4j1.6

Comment: Hi ! Np :) Because the `dom4j 1.6` is an old version i worked with in a project which was created in 2004 and with `Hibernate 5.1` they used a newest version and surely they modified some methods in the class `STAXEventReader` that's why he didn't catch the class even if they have the same name.

Comment: can i get +1 for my answer please ? thnx :)

Comment: Yeah sure!!! +1 for you :)

Comment: Can you please show how you excluded it in the maven pom file?

Comment: @DavidR Please see below updated answer.

Comment: another great q and a.  so stackoverflow reviewers, why did you not close this one like you did this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27589543/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-nosuchfielderror-trace ?  FYI, this q and a save my HOURS in hiib 3 to 5 upgrade....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to [Hohenheim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4871427/hohenheim) to point out the version issue.

> Hibernate core 5.1.0.Final include dom4j-1.6.1 jar which throws this
>   error. To fix this, need to exclude dom4j-1.6.1 from hibernate-core
>   and include dom4j-1.6 in your pom.

I am not able find the exact reason why this is happening.

This is how I excluded dom4j from pom in hibernate dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <!-- Exclude SLF4j to avoid version conflicts (we have 1.6.6, this drags 
                in 1.6.1) -->
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <!-- Exclude dom4j to avoid version conflicts (we have 1.6, this drags 
                in 1.6.1) -->
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

I used Ivy dependency manager and in my case I remove dom4j from core dependency and again add the last version 1.6.1 and that worked for me.

```
<dependency org="org.hibernate" name="hibernate-core" rev="5.2.8.Final">
    <exclude  org="dom4j"/>
</dependency>

<dependency org="dom4j" name="dom4j" rev="1.6.1"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case with the same problem I solve it setting this versions in pom.xml:

> - Spring version 4.3.7.RELEASE
> - Hibernate version 4.1.9.Final

I **did't use** `<exclusions>` at all and I added dom4j with version 1.4.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my scenario, same stacktrace, I followed the answers without success. The solution was to remove dom4j from .m2/repository because apparently the jar was corrupt, and after downloaded again the problem was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You won't need to apply exclusions. Simply fix this by deleting your local repository and then re download libraries by doing the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> + force update.

Doing this solved the issue for me.