# Context initialization failed : Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactoryBean'

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I was trying Spring + JPA + Hibernate on my local but I am getting below error. I tried to change exclude the version of dom4j(as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36222306/caused-by-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-dom4j-io-staxeventreader/43286421)) but is of no use .

Here is Error

```
2018-01-03 02:01:40 ERROR DispatcherServlet:502 - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactoryBean' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/configuration/recon-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/dom4j/io/STAXEventReader
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1078)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:857)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:634).........
```

Below is the POM.xml 
[image]

And the Servlet.xml

[image]

I have tried to remove dom4j but it does not work and also changed hibernate version from 5.2.12 to 5.0.12 but looks like it does not work.

Thanks in advance for your suggestions .

Comment: Looks like this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36222306/caused-by-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-dom4j-io-staxeventreader

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.dom4j.io.STAXEventReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36222306/caused-by-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-dom4j-io-staxeventreader)

Comment: @Ralph : I have tried to implement the solution given in link but it is not working. I have mentioned same in my question.

Comment: After further reducing hibernate version to 4.3.11.Final it is working it is working fine. Not sure why not working for 5.0 onward versions of Hibernate

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answear:
[Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.dom4j.io.STAXEventReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36222306/caused-by-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-dom4j-io-staxeventreader)
Also your pom dependencies section looks way overcomplicated.

Comment: Thanks for comment , but I had this link already mentioned in the question. Ultimately I have to degrade my Hibernate , Spring and Spring-jpa versions as below :  <org.springframework.version>4.3.12.RELEASE</org.springframework.version> 
<org.hibernate.version>4.3.11.Final</org.hibernate.version>        Spring-JPA<version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>